# Poor Vector3 decimals precision in subtraction C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, 3d

I want to know the direction a spaceship is actually moving to, its path of motion. I am doing it like so

```
void Start() {
   prevPos = transform.position;
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    Vector3 currPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 motion = currPos - prevPos;

    Debug.Log("Current position: " + currPos + " Previous position: " + prevPos + " Difference: " + motion);

    prevPos = currPos;
}
```

The problem is that each frame the ship doesn't move too much, and the difference between `currPos` and `prevPos` (I'm guessing) is in the decimals (`0.0530` for example). From what I read Vectors go up to 7 decimals, yet `motion` equals (0, 0, 0) most frames.

**In the Debug above I get these results**

Current position: (0, 0, 0.5) Previous position: (0, 0, 0.4) Difference: (0, 0, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Debug.Log` function is made to truncate `Vector3` on purpose to make it more readable. If you need to show all decimals, simply make a function to concatenate and show each individual component of the `Vector3`.

```
void PrintVector3(Vector3 message, int type = 1)
{
    if (type == 1)
        Debug.Log("X: " + message.x + "  Y: " + message.y + "  Z:" + message.z);
    if (type == 2)
        Debug.LogWarning("X: " + message.x + "  Y: " + message.y + "  Z:" + message.z);
    if (type == 3)
        Debug.LogError("X: " + message.x + "  Y: " + message.y + "  Z:" + message.z);
}
```

Also when you concatenate `string` with `Vector3`, you also lose the decimal places. You can make a simple function to concatenate string and Vector3  an return the string. This string you can then print with `Debug.Log`.

```
string Concat(string val, Vector3 vec)
{
    return val + " (" + vec.x + ", " + vec.y + ", " + vec.z + ")";
}
```

Comment: Yeah. You should create new question with the problem. Also add the raycast code and explain what's happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: With the Debug.ray I wanted it to go from current position to previous position, so I used those arguments (currPos, prevPos...) but the arguments of that function are `(from, direction...)` and not `from, to...`

Comment: @RealAnyOne to compute `direction` just normalize the vector `to - from`.

Comment: The Debug.Log function logs whatever object it is given by calling its ToString method. It's the Vector3.ToString method that does the rounding.

Answer (score 0):

As SilentSin points out, Vector3.ToString() is being called for you. If you call ToString yourself, you can control the precision of the rounding.

```
Debug.Log("Current position: " + currPos.ToString("N4") + " Previous position: " + prevPos.ToString("N4") + " Difference: " + motion.ToString("N4"));
Debug.LogFormat("Current position: {0} Previous position: {1} Difference: {2}", currPos.ToString("N4"), prevPos.ToString("N4"), motion.ToString("N4"));
```

I find this useful for debugging as I can control the real estate claimed by each value.